# Regex PRCE PHP preg_match_all: How do remove empty nodes in matches array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, pcre, preg-match-all

```
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum';
$re = '/(?<AA>Any)|(?<BB>Lorem)/ui';
$nMatches = preg_match_all($re, $text, $aMatches);
```

`$aMatches` will contain the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Lorem
        )

    [AA] => Array (       //  do not include to result matches array
            [0] =>        //  because have not match for this part
        )

    [1] => Array (
            [0] => 
        )

    [BB] => Array (
            [0] => Lorem
        )

    [2] => Array (
            [0] => Lorem
        )
)
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to return the array without nodes for named parts that have no matches?

```
 Array (
        [0] => Array (
                [0] => Lorem
            )

        {there was [AA] && [1], but have not returned because empty} 

        [BB] => Array (
                [0] => Lorem
            )

        [1] => Array (        // changed to 1
                [0] => Lorem
            )
    )
```

Comment: You can clean them at least with `$aMatches = array_filter($aMatches);`

Comment: Better if regex will not return.
Remove from a result array is not difficult, but will better if an empty nodes will not come from regex.

Comment: Is there any reason why they have different names?

Comment: @salathe: Yes, this regex is very simplified. In real I am using much more named groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for regex, you can see [@Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390828/regex-prce-php-preg-match-all-how-do-remove-empty-nodes-in-matches-array/5392660#5392660). More generally, when just manipulating arrays, you can use a combination of [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) and [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to do that. `array_filter` without a callback will strip the values that evaluates to `false` (`== false` not `=== false`, see [empty](http://php.net/empty)).

For a single-level array:

```
$array = array('foo', '', 'bar');
$clean_array = array_filter($array);
```

For a 2D array:

```
$clean_array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
```

Comment: **!!!!!!!!!!**
`This answer does not solve to answer, but is much closer to solution, because how I understand It is not possible solve with regex.`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar by using the branch-reset operator :

`/(?|(?<BB>Any)|(?<BB>Lorem))/ui`

outputs

- [0]=> array

  - [0]=>Lorem
- [BB]=> array
  - [0]=>Lorem
- [1]=> array
  - [0]=>Lorem

By using this operator the named groups must have the **same name.**

You test the regexp [here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=715).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but "without nodes for named parts that have no matches" it is mean, if part have matches them must be returned to array with your name. This is problem. Need remove only parts that haven't matches. All other parts must be leaved with their names.

Comment: so did you try array_filter ?