# PHP regex - weird issue with multiple group capture

Tags: php, regex

The code:

```
$pattern = '~(/(?P<lang>en|ru))?/foo(/(?P<bar>bar))?~';

preg_match($pattern, '/foo', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
/*output:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "/foo"
}*/
preg_match($pattern, '/foo/bar', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
/*output:
array(7) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "/foo/bar"
  [1] =>
  string(0) ""
  'lang' =>
  string(0) ""
  [2] =>
  string(0) ""
  [3] =>
  string(4) "/bar"
  'bar' =>
  string(3) "bar"
  [4] =>
  string(3) "bar"
}*/
```

The question: why the hell does it capture `<lang>` in the second preg_match call and how do I fix it?

P.S. I tried this regex on https://www.regex101.com and there it captures correctly, but on my machine with PHP7, it does not. I get the feeling that regex101 filters the output.

Comment: No idea what you mean but perhaps lazy matching can help: `(/(?P<lang>en|ru))??/foo(/(?P<bar>bar))?`

Comment: I mean that it should not capture `lang` when there is no match. It doesn't make any sense. And no, adding another `?` did not help.

Comment: Please clarify. I see in your code demo that `lang` is empty: `'lang' =>  string(0) ""`. No text has been captured.

Comment: It is empty, but still captured. It should not even be there in that array. The output should be `0 => '/foo/bar', 1 => '/bar', 'bar' => 'bar', 2 => 'bar'`.

Comment: @jurchiks: It is not possible. If you define a capturing group, it is always there, in the resulting array. You will have to remove it manually if you do not want it to appear there. Say, with `array_filter($matches)`

Comment: That's just how `preg_match()` works ... if *any* capturing group has a match, all of them will be returned.

Comment: Once you have set `$matches` simply run it through `array_filter` and it will remove the empty values, such as `lang`

Comment: ...welcome to PHP :-D

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work the same in other languages?

Comment: there are hundreds of languages, which ones?

Comment: @jurchiks usually you don't directly work on `$matches`. You check if a group exists, cherry pick what you need and work with your new variables.

Comment: just clean the `$matches` with `array_filter`, bang, problem is solved as soon as it's created.

Comment: And look at [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/fD1qG1/1): if you enable "SHOW NON-PARTICIPATING GROUPS" in the Options, you will see all the groups info on the right. The default behavior is just to hide them.

Comment: Yeah, that checkbox really should be checked by default. Well, this blows.

Comment: Calm down dear, have a cup of tea and then consider that most people who use PHP know far less than you do about it. Now dwell in that smugness for a minute or two :)

Comment: I suggest closing with [Regex PRCE PHP preg_match_all: How do remove empty nodes in matches array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390828/regex-prce-php-preg-match-all-how-do-remove-empty-nodes-in-matches-array)

Comment: @HamZa - this is route matching; for example, symfony works on $matches: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L141

Comment: @jurchiks I'm not saying don't work with `$matches` at all. The way you have formulated your regex, it will pollute the `$matches` array. Which is why you most of the time try to select what you need.

Comment: Well it's not an option in this case.

Comment: Why is it not an option? I can't easily think of a situation you can't further edit a PHP variable returned by a PCRE regex before end use?

Comment: @Martin - I don't think you understood correctly; it is not an option to not use `$matches`.

Comment: Ok. Well as I've said, you *can* use `$matches` but simply add the `$matches = array_filer($matches)` right after the `preg_match` and then it only returns to you the populated arrays (exactly as the regex101.com shows by default) . I thought you were saying that further adjustment to `$matches` was not an option.

Comment: I did that. It's really not a solution I'd like, but hey, this is PHP...

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, that's simply how regex works. It's fairly universal to regexes, as far as I know. It even has parallels in programming in general, such as how Java requires a `String` returning function to return a `String` (unless it throws an error).

In PHP, use `array_filter` on `$matches` to remove empty entries.

Also, I suggest using non-capturing groups `(?:)` to cut the clutter:

`(?:/(?P<lang>en|ru))?/foo(?:/(?P<bar>bar))?`

Or split it into 2 regexes: `(?:/(?P<lang>en|ru))` and `/foo(?:/(?P<bar>bar))`.